# Image on JPanel only flickers when moved

Tags: java, image

I have a `BufferedImage` that I draw that doesn't show up unless I resize the window, and even then it only flickers:

```
// Remember, this is a JFrame class
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paint(g2d);
    Graphics p = drawPanel.getGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        BufferedImage im = images[i];
        int ciw = getWidth() / 3;
        int cih = getHeight() / 2;
        int xpos = i % 3;
        int ypos = i / 3;
        int ix = i * ciw * xpos;
        int iy = i * cih * ypos;
        int iw = ciw;
        int ih = cih;
        p.drawImage(im, ix, iy, iw, ih, null);
    }
//  drawPanel.paintComponents(p);
//  drawPanel.repaint();
}
```

I have done `drawPanel.setDoubleBuffered(true)`.

If you want to see the whole code: [`https://github.com/firestar115/BCMaker`](https://github.com/firestar115/BCMaker)

Comment: Did you try double buffering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `BufferedImage` to draw your images on. Then, draw that `BufferedImage` on to `drawPanel.getGraphics()`. Do not call `repaint()`.

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
//  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
//  super.paint(g2d);
    Graphics p = bi.getGraphics();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        BufferedImage im = images[i];
        int ciw = getWidth() / 3;
        int cih = getHeight() / 2;
        int xpos = i % 3;
        int ypos = i / 3;
        int ix = i * ciw * xpos;
        int iy = i * cih * ypos;
        int iw = ciw;
        int ih = cih;
        p.drawImage(im, ix, iy, iw, ih, null);
    }
    drawPanel.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
//  drawPanel.paintComponents(p);
//  drawPanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code contains several things you shouldn't do.

Don't override `paint()`. Override `paintComponent()` instead.

Don't do this:

```
Graphics2D p = (Graphics2D) drawPanel.getGraphics();
```

Instead, just use the Graphics that were passed into the paintComponent() method.

Don't call `paint()` or `paintComponent()` from your own painting code.

Instead, just call `repaint()` when you want your `paintComponent()` method to be called. If you want it to be called multiple times, then use a Timer. Don't call `repaint()` from inside your `paintComponent()` method either.

If you want more specific help, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1+, `Don't call paint() or paintComponent() from your own painting code. Instead, just call repaint().` , just to clarify, you should not invoke paint() or paintComponent() or repaint() from within your painting code.

Comment: Thanks @camickr. I've edited my answer to (hopefully) be a little more obvious.

Comment: I tried a timer with a delay of 1, and it lagged horrendously. Also, JFrame does not have a `paintCompnent()` method, it has `paintComponents()`

Comment: @moo_we_all_do Then don't extend JFrame- extend JPanel instead. And you'll have to look into proper threading (you have to factor in the time between frames when updating your game state) to get a non-laggy game loop.